Use the offscreen API with webextension-polyfill
I'm trying to upgrade to Manifest version 3 a cross-browser extension that uses webextension-polyfill and Typecript. I'm stuck on trying to do something similar to https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/develop/migrate/to-service-workers#move-dom-and-window because I can't seem to import offscreen from webextension-polyfill. Is there some way I can import offscreen in this project, or is there an alternative approach that would work to replace the usage of window in the service worker?

Don't use the polyfill. Use chrome.offscreen directly.

@woxxom but this browser extension needs to work in Firefox and Safari too.

Those browsers don't have the actual API, so it won't work anyway. It's Chromium-only. In other browsers you don't need it. The only reason for its existence is the Google's problematic decision to switch to the service workers in their extensions.
